# Which SAS JBOD module for NetApp DS4243?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sas, netapp, jbod

Does anyone know what the SAS JBOD module is called (model number perhaps) that works for NetApp's DS4243 disk array?

I can find controllers on ebay, but not a single SAS JBOD module.

Afterwards it will be used on Linux.

Comment: This is not meant to be attached to a server. It's a Netapp shelf.

Comment: Are you trying to build another ZFS cluster? [Use the info described here](https://github.com/ewwhite/zfs-ha/wiki).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an IOM3 X5712A-R6 I believe

Comment: I have never seen RJ45 on a JBOD module before. What are they used for?

Comment: They are used for out of band disk management.